# When sould I use HandlerInterceptor and ClientHttpRequestInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, http, resttemplate, interceptor

I need to create a http interceptor for my spring boot app to check if the request's authorization heathers are valid, so I searched and it seems that I can use HandlerInterceptor or ClientHttpRequestInterceptor to do it.

What would be the ideal interceptor in this case? I need all requests to check this and deny access if they don't pass but to me it looks like both of the interceptors do the same thing, so what is the difference between each one?

Important detail:
I'm using @RestController to create my routes and if the route has an specific annotation (something like @IgnoreAuthentication) the interceptor won't need to check the authentication.